# Python efficient implementation of a fix-sized ordered by value hash map

Tags: python-3.x, ordered-map

I want to keep a list of the top N entries based on their value, and update it every time a larger value is received. For example, if `N=3`

```
LIST
id: 'abc' --> 323
id: 'cbs' --> 321
id: 'aac' --> 123

New entry: id: 'aaa' --> 101. Ignore
New entry: id: 'zzz' --> 111. Ignore
New entry: id: 'cwl' --> 322. Update list

LIST
id: 'abc' --> 323
id: 'cwl' --> 322
id: 'cbs' --> 321
```

In C++ this could be implemented with `std::map` of size N, adding to it and deleting its last entry. What's the best way in Python? Assume version > 3.6

Comment: `std::map` is ordered by key and not by value, so even that one would not work for what you want to do. Besides, that keeps the whole map sorted the whole time, which is not the most efficient for what you are trying to do. In your case you should keep the values in a heap (minheap, not maxheap!) of size N and when you get a new element compare the value with the top of the heap. You would need also to keep the inverse map, in order to know which element to replace, if needed. Python has a heap implementation in the module `heapq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your comparison with C++ wouldn't work so easily, since `std::map` is sorted by key and not by value (though you could work around it by keeping also the inverse map in parallel).

For implementing something similar in python, first of all you can realize that for your specific case you don't need the elements to be sorted the whole time, the important thing you care about is to know what your smallest element is. You can achieve this easily by keeping a heap (minheap) of max size N with all values you have so far. When you get a new element, you just need to compare the value with the head (smallest element) of your heap, and if it is bigger, remove the head of the heap (and the corresponding entry in your map), and add the new element to the map and the value to the heap. Again, you would need to keep also the inverse map in order to know which element to delete from the map.

Python has a heap implementation in the module `heapq`, see reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html).

**EDIT**

For completeness, I will add here that although there is no native implementation of sorted maps in python, there are external packages you can use for this, e.g. [sortedmap](https://pypi.org/project/sortedmap/), but since for your specific case this is not necessary, I would still propose to go with a heap that does not require external packages and not add unnecessary dependencies.